# Cannot implicitly convert type "System.DateTime" to "LearnScan.LearnUser.NullableDateTime"

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datetime, nullable

Trying to set a value for a create user soap call and when setting a startdate for a new user:

```
DateTime? dt = DateTime.Now;
emptyUsr.StartDate = dt;
```

It returns an error of "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime' to 'LearnScan.LearnUser.NullableDateTime'" I was under the impression that DateTime? sets to nullable?

The `StartDate` property has type `LearnScan.LearnUser.NullableDateTime` which is defined as:

```
public partial class NullableDateTime : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {
    internal static object DateTime;
    private bool isNullField;

    private System.DateTime valueField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=0)]
    public bool IsNull {
        get {
            return this.isNullField;
        }
        set {
            this.isNullField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("IsNull");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=1)]
    public System.DateTime Value {
        get {
            return this.valueField;
        }
        set {
            this.valueField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Value");
        }
    }

    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
        if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
            propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

*Solution - It wanted values for each `emptyUsr.StartDate.IsNull = false` and `emptyUsr.StartDate.Value= DateTime.Now;`

Comment: Read the error carefully. It talks about *LearnScan.LearnUser.NullableDateTime*, not `Nullable<DateTime>`. The error will point to the offending line and I'd bet it's `emptyUsr.StartDate = dt;`. What is the type of `StartDate` ?

Comment: Yes sorry I'm new. How do I cast to NullableDateTime?

Comment: There's no such thing. The error complains that you tried to set a DateTime value to a property using *your custom type*.

Comment: emptyUsr.StartDate need to be a DateTime?....or cast dt to DateTime like this....emptyUsr.StartDate = (DateTime)dt;

Comment: This question can't be answered until you add the definition for `LearnScan.LearnUser.NullableDateTime` (or you change the type of the `StartDate` property to `DateTime?`).

Comment: @ChrisCatignani this assumes that the OP mangled the error message pretty badly. And added a non-existend namespace. It makes sense though

Comment: I didn't create the custom type as this is soap api integration. I'm not sure what they are wanting to be set or how I can convert it to what they want.

Comment: @dustin How did you create the SOAP client? This sounds either like a bad proxy or a bad service definition. Optional fields should appear as *optional* in the service's XSD. Seems like whoever created that service created a custom type instead. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32558502/how-to-serialize-nullable-datetime-in-a-wcf-datacontract) shows how optional dates should be handled

Comment: I didnt create the SOAP client. My app talking to a 3rd party service that created it. Im just trying to use their SOAP api.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I just happen to be having a round with a nullable DateTimeOffset..

Comment: Just to clear this up ...DateTime? dt = DateTime.Now; does not make it null. DateTime? dt; does.

Comment: When I view the Reference I see 
     
`public partial class NullableDateTime : object, 
    
System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {internal static object DateTime;
        private bool isNullField;
        
       private System.DateTime valueField;`

Comment: Just try this: emptyUsr.StartDate = DateTime.Now;

Comment: @ChrisCatignani That returns the same error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime' to 'LearnScan.LearnUser.NullableDateTime'"

Comment: Please add the full definition of `LearnScan.LearnUser.NullableDateTime` to the question, no-one can tell you how to construct one from a `DateTime?` otherwise.

Comment: @Lee Here is the full definition https://pastebin.com/ZPRvfpg1

Comment: I solved it. See OP for solution. Thank you all for your insights.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an implicit conversion from `DateTime?` to your `NullableDateTime` class:

```
namespace LearnScan.LearnUser {
    public partial class NullableDateTime
    {
        public static implicit operator NullableDateTime(DateTime? dt)
        {
            if(dt.HasValue)
            {
                return new NullableDateTime { IsNull = false, Value = dt.Value };
            }
            else
            {
                 return new NullableDateTime { IsNull = true };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that before and It didnt work. Anyway I fixed it. It was looking for
 `emptyUsr.StartDate.Value = DateTime.Now;` 
    `emptyUsr.StartDate.IsNull = false;`

Comment: @dustin - You tried what before? How did it not work? Your fix is basically what this answer suggests.

Answer (score 1):

The `NullableDateTime` externally-defined type (since that is *not* part of the regular C# set of libraries and APIs) is not the same as `DateTime?`. Although its short name might trick you into thinking that, its full name `LearnScan.LearnUser.NullableDateTime` tells you that it is very different from `System.DateTime?` (which is the actual full name of `DateTime?` in .NET). You need to understand how `NullableDateTime` was implemented and how to use it. It might be a different approach to a nullable DateTime type built upon the DateTime struct .NET offers, as of the short snippet you provided in the comments.